# Localization in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have done localization in my PCL project , in my PCL there is a resource folder contain two resource one default English and other Arabic the culture is ar-AS. I can run it on my emulator but not in device what should be the reason. I'm now on android project

Comment: What do you mean by "I can run it on my emulator but not in device"? Tell us about the error message, exception, whatever.

Comment: there is no exception if i testing in emulator. I can change the language by changing language in custom locale but it not working in my device. If i change my device language the app language is not changing hope you got my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the problem of my Language Culture Name, i added Language Culture Name "ar-sa" this was not need i just removed the SA it work nicely

Answer (score 2):

> [Doesn't work in DEBUG mode (Android only)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/#Doesnt_work_in_DEBUG_mode_Android_only)
>
> If the translated strings are working in your RELEASE Android builds
>   but not while debugging, right-click on the Android Project and select
>   Options > Build > Android Build and ensure that the Fast assembly
>   deployment is NOT ticked. This option causes problems with loading
>   resources and should not be used if you are testing localized apps.